# Calculated column for sum of last three values

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need to create a calculated column that returns the average of the last three values in a column.  much like the offset function in excel

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Calculated Columns cannot reference other list items. They can only access other columns in the same list.

There is a possible workflow solution if you are using SharePoint 2013 and later, and the 2013 style workflows are supported on your farm.

Are you wanting the average of the last three items in the column based on some sort, or the average of the last three items before any one item?